# Как правильно сделать асинхронные запросы, зависящие друг от друга RxJava Android

Tags: android, rxjava

я новичек в RxJava. Задача следующая: есть 3 запроса

1. Получение токена
2. Валидация токена
3. Получение id сессии

Каждый запрос зависит от ответа предыдущего, т.е. сначала я делаю запрос на получение токена, если токен получен, то нужно передать его во второй запрос на проверку валидности, и затем, если токен прошел валидность, нужно передать его в третий запрос для получения id сессии. Вопрос в том, как это сделать правильно и красиво с помощью RxJava?

Я знаю, что в целом я мог сделать как-то так:

```
        apiService.createRequestToken()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .subscribe(object: Observer<RequestTokenResponse> {
                override fun onComplete() { }
                override fun onSubscribe(d: Disposable) { }

                override fun onNext(t: RequestTokenResponse) {
                    apiService.validateRequestToken(username, password, t.requestToken)
                        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                        .subscribe(object: Observer<RequestTokenResponse> {
                            override fun onComplete() { }
                            override fun onSubscribe(d: Disposable) { }

                            override fun onNext(t: RequestTokenResponse) {
                                apiService.createSession(t.requestToken)
                                    .subscribe(object: Observer<SessionResponse> {
                                        override fun onComplete() { }
                                        override fun onSubscribe(d: Disposable) { }

                                        override fun onNext(t: SessionResponse) {

                                        }

                                        override fun onError(e: Throwable) {
                                            Log.i(TAG, e.localizedMessage)
                                        }
                                    })
                            }

                            override fun onError(e: Throwable) {
                                Log.i(TAG, e.localizedMessage)
                            }
                        })

                }

                override fun onError(e: Throwable) {
                    Log.i(TAG, e.localizedMessage)
                }
            })
```

Но мне кажется, что есть более компактный и правильный способ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно действительно проще. Примерно так:

```
apiService.createRequestToken()
    .switchMap(t -> apiService.validateRequestToken(username, password, t.requestToken).map(ignored -> t))
    .switchMap(t -> apiService.createSession(t.requestToken))
    .subscribe(
        result -> { /*обработка успеха*/ },
        error -> { /*обработка ошибки*/ }
     );
```

Comment: Спасибо, этот код действительно работает. Есть небольшой вопрос, я правильно понимаю, что если например первый запрос createRequestToken будет неудачный, то следующие запросы выполняться не будут, а ошибка пойдет в блок error?

Comment: @Stenol_53, да всё верно. Ошибка на любом этапе цепочку прервёт и ошибку выдаст в лямбде в subscribe методе.

Comment: Спасибо большое, теперь все стало ясно!